# ODOO POS Weight Scale on RS232

Tags: serial-port, odoo, point-of-sale

I have a weighing scale manufactured by a local vendor. It can be connected to the RS232 Serial Port to my PC and has been working great so far. Now trying to use it with ODOO v8 POS, however, ODOO does not read weights from this machine although other programs, including the Windows Accessories --> Communication --> Hyperterminal.

Is it that ODOO does not work with RS232 for reading a weighing scale, or something that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Odoo pos uses the postbox (Iot Box from v12) modules to communicate with a scale. The modules are mended to be installed on a raspberry pi but it is also possible to use your POS computer.

I would recommend to upgrade to a newer version of Odoo because there is only support for the 3 last versions, that are now 10, 11, 12 (and all subversions)

Read more about posbox here:
https://www.odoo.com/documentation/user/11.0/point_of_sale/overview/setup.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer and I am trying to explore it with Odoo V11 (CE). Could you please explain it more on how to use weighing scale connected to my POS computer? My POS computer is not running Odoo server, but is a odoo client machine.

Comment: The machine you connect the devices to has to run a Odoo server as explained in the 'Image building process' section, but the easiest way to make it work is by buying a raspberry-pi, it is not expensive at all and you can install a rebuild  image made by Odoo on it.

Answer (score 0):

Odoo IotBox allows to connect an external scale to Odoo. Unfortunately, altough infrastructure is coded to easily implement additional drivers, only drivers for two protocols are provided out-of-the-box ( Mettled Toledo 8217 and Adam AZExtra)

If you want to code your own driver, you will need to study your scale protocol, write a new python file and put in the drivers directory of the IotBox (`/root_bypass_ramdisks/home/pi/odoo/addons/hw_drivers/iot_handlers/drivers/` for IotBox 21.10).

For example:

```
from collections import namedtuple
import logging
import re
import serial
import threading
import time

from odoo import http
from odoo.addons.hw_drivers.controllers.proxy import proxy_drivers
from odoo.addons.hw_drivers.event_manager import event_manager
from odoo.addons.hw_drivers.iot_handlers.drivers.SerialBaseDriver import SerialDriver, SerialProtocol, serial_connection
from odoo.addons.hw_drivers.iot_handlers.drivers.SerialScaleDriver import ScaleDriver

_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# Only needed to ensure compatibility with older versions of Odoo
ACTIVE_SCALE = None
new_weight_event = threading.Event()

ScaleProtocol = namedtuple('ScaleProtocol', SerialProtocol._fields + ('zeroCommand', 'tareCommand', 'clearCommand', 'autoResetWeight'))


KernDEProtocol = ScaleProtocol(
    name='Kern DE test driver',
    baudrate=9600,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    timeout=1,
    writeTimeout=1,
    measureRegexp=b"^[\sM][\s-]\s*([0-9.]+)\skg",             
    statusRegexp=None,
    commandDelay=0.2,
    measureDelay=0.5,
    newMeasureDelay=0.2,
    commandTerminator=b'',
    measureCommand=b'w',    
    zeroCommand=None,       
    tareCommand=b't',
    clearCommand=None,      
    emptyAnswerValid=False,
    autoResetWeight=False,
)





class KernDEDriver(ScaleDriver):
    """Driver for the Kern DE serial scale."""
    _protocol = KernDEProtocol

    def __init__(self, identifier, device):
        super(KernDEDriver, self).__init__(identifier, device)
        self.device_manufacturer = 'Kern'

    @classmethod
    def supported(cls, device):
        """Checks whether the device, which port info is passed as argument, is supported by the driver.

        :param device: path to the device
        :type device: str
        :return: whether the device is supported by the driver
        :rtype: bool
        """

        protocol = cls._protocol

        try:
            with serial_connection(device['identifier'], protocol, is_probing=True) as connection:
                _logger.info('Try... device %s with protocol %s' % (device, protocol.name))
                connection.write(b'w' + protocol.commandTerminator)
                time.sleep(protocol.commandDelay)
                answer = connection.read(18)
                _logger.info('Answer: [%s] from device %s with protocol %s' % (answer, device, protocol.name))
                if answer.find(b' kg \r\n')!=-1:
                    _logger.info('OK %s with protocol %s' % (device, protocol.name))
                    return True
        except serial.serialutil.SerialTimeoutException:
            _logger.exception('Serial Timeout %s with protocol %s' % (device, protocol.name))
            pass
        except Exception:
            _logger.exception('Error while probing %s with protocol %s' % (device, protocol.name))
        return False
```

Key parts of the above code are:

- protocol details (baudrate, bytesize, stopbits, parity)
- codes to write to the scale to read, zero, or tare (measureCommand, zeroCommand, tareCommand)
- regex expression to capture the response (measureRegexp)
- function `supported` that will be launched at start of odoo service and is needed to identify the scale model. If all identifications available fail (or the scale is powered off on the startup cycle of the IotBox), the scale will be marked by IotBox as as Adam AZExtra

You can take a look at https://github.com/ellery-it/odoo-serial-scale-drivers for more details and examples for two Kern scales

Disclaimer: I am the owner of the  odoo-serial-scale-drivers github page